# Angular2 + Express.js: Return CSV and offer downloadable file?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have this code in my ng2 component:

```
data => {
    let blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/csv" }); 
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "data.csv);
}
```

Then there is a file saved, but the contents of the file read:

`Response with status: 200 OK for URL: https://MYURL/URI/data.csv`

My backend is node/express, do I have to create a stream for this or does it work with direct file access like in the old days?

This is my backend at the moment, how can I alter it to return a stream?

```
'use strict';

const Transactions = require('../../models').transaction;

module.exports = function * details(req, res) {

  logger.debug(' Get TME details ' + req.currentTME._id);

  const transaction = yield Transactions.findOne({
    _tme: req.currentTME.id
  }).lean();


  return res
    .json({
      status: constants.status.SUCCESS,
      timemodel: req.currentTME,
      linkedInfo: {
        transaction
      }
    });
};
```

Full Server Call:

```
 request(url: string, data: any, method: RequestMethod, showErrorDialog = true): Observable<any> {

    const requestOptionsArgs: RequestOptionsArgs = {

        url: this.baseUrl + url,
        method: method,
        headers: this.createHeaders(),
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    this.log.info(this.getCurl(requestOptionsArgs), this);

    const requestOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions(requestOptionsArgs);

    return this.intercept(
        this.http.request(new Request(requestOptions)).timeout(3000),
        requestOptionsArgs,
        showErrorDialog
    ).share();
}
```

Comment: Please show more code like your HTTP call to the server. I suspect you're not doing `res.map(x => x.json())` because that looks like a Response.toString().

Comment: Ok I added the code.

Comment: I don't know what `this.intercept` is, but as far as I can tell, what I said is correct: you need to map the response to something (based on what I can see here). What that might end up being is `this.http.request(...).map(x => x.json())`. That should give you actual data.

Comment: thanks I will try and reply

Comment: I needed to access `data._body` instead of `data`. All working now!